# Continuous integration and Continuous deployment in Azure Data factory

Tags: azure, azure-data-factory

I want to do continuous integration and deployment in Azure Data factory. I'm not able to find any specific document explaining this.

How can I do it or where can I read about it?

Answer (score 1):

**To build your project**, you can use msbuild - just like it's done in Visual Studio. It will validate syntax, check references between json configurations and check all dependencies. If you are using Visual Studio Team Services as CI server you can use Visual Studio Build step in build configuration to do it. However, it requires to install ADF tools for VS on build agent machine.

**To deploy**, you can try:

1. Powershell. For example, you can use [Set-AzureRmDataFactoryV2Dataset](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/azurerm.datafactoryv2/Set-azurermdatafactoryv2dataset?view=azurermps-4.4.1) to deploy datasets. There are similar commands for all other configurations and for version 1 of Azure Data Factory as well.
2. If you are using VSTS, you can try [this 3rd party extension](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=liprec.vsts-publish-adf). It allows to deploy json configurations and start/pause pipelines. I'm not sure if it works with ADF v2.

Comment: I need to deploy the ADF script using powershell..in the powershell how will i refer the ADF files..   instead of referring local path which path do i need to refer..                                                        
 foreach($file in Get-ChildItem "C:\Visual Studio 2015\Projects\ADFCICD1402\" -filter "Linked") New-AzureRmDataFactoryLinkedService -ResourceGroupName "AD" -DataFactoryName "ADFCICD" -Name $file.BaseName -File $file.FullName -Force | Format-List

Comment: I need to take a build using Powershell instead of VSTS option. If you can provide any links or code for this it would be helpful

Answer (score 0):

You can use the VSTS GIT integration with ADF v2 UX to do continous deployment and continuous integration. VSTS GIT integration allows you to choose a feature/development branch or create a new one in your VSTS GIT repo. You can work in your feature/development branch and create PR in VSTS GIT to merge your changes to the master branch. You can then publish to your data factory using ADF v2 UX. Please try this and let us know if this doesn't work for you or you face any issues.